# Jenkins HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request even without making any request

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jenkins, devops

[image: Jenkins Error screen]

I keep getting this error each time I try to do anything jenkins running on aws ubuntu
I have tried every fix I know
The error appears each time I try to setup a configuration on jenkins manage

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you are using reverse proxy and trying to access Jenkins without the preserved client ip (it could be changed by settings of your reverse proxy server)

ref: https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/instance-navigation-often-fails-with-crumb-issuer-errors